# How to apply a property only to the submit button

Tags: html, css

I'd like to normalize some elements in my page, like put some margin/padding on the submit button.

Tried with `input.submit {margin:0; padding:1px 6px 1px 6px;}` but seems that it doesnt work. How can I do this using CSS 2.1?

Comment: Not all browsers have CSS 2.1 fully implemented. Is there any particular reason you need to support them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most reliably with CSS 2.1 I think you've got the option of applying a `class` or `id` to the button, or isolating the button inside of a particular parent element.

Otherwise CSS 2.1 *does* support the [attribute=value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs) selector notation, so:

```
input[type=submit],
/* or */
button[type=submit]
```

Should work. This is, however, variably reliable in Internet Explorer (although, to my surprise) is, according to [PPK, of Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), available in IE>=7.

**Edited** to further explore the question:

The reason that `input.submit {margin:0; padding:1px 6px 1px 6px;}` "doesn't work" is because that selector, `input.submit` would select `input` elements with a class-name of `submit`. Unless you gave the submit button that class-name there's no matching element in your html.

With jQuery there's the possibility to match submit elements with the selector `$('input:submit')`, but that's not a valid CSS-selector (so far as I'm currently aware); the nearest thing that CSS can offer is, as noted above, the `input[type=submit]`.

---

Further reference: [CSS2 [attr] selector, at Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_attribute.html).

Answer (score 1):

In CSS3 compatible browsers you could use:

```
input[type="submit"] {margin:0; padding:1px 6px 1px 6px;}
```

If you can't use CSS3, you would have to set a class on the submit input:

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit form" />
```

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: `input[type=submit]` [**is** valid under CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs).

Comment: Ok, I thought it was CSS3. Guess I've been working too long trying to make things look pretty in browsers that don't even fully support CSS2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `input[type="submit"]` is a valid CSS 2.1 selector.

Source: [W3C CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching)

Comment: Ok, I thought it was CSS3. Guess I've been working too long trying to make things look pretty in browsers that don't even fully support CSS2.